# use for loop in timer android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, countdowntimer, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to create a timer that will run x number of times for a given duration.  Example: 10 is the number of seconds that the timer should run.  3 is the number of times that the 10 second timer should complete.

Ideally it would start the 10 second (or any variable time) countdown the first time. 
Then play a sound.
Then start the countdown again (second time).
Then play a sound.
Then start the countdown again (third time).
Then play a sound and stop executing and do something else.

So far i have create a for loop that calls the timer method but it only seems to run 1x.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
    private void startRound(){
    for ( int i = 0; i < mRounds; i++){
        startTimer();
    }
}

private void startTimer(){
        CountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeft, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeft = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textView.setText("FINISHED");
                mTimerRunning = false;
                mButtonStartPause.setText("START");
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ;
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }.start();
        mTimerRunning = true;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **for loop** is not waiting for the **CountDownTimer** to finish. And would start 3 countdown timers ~instantly.
For repeating simple periodic tasks an Handler is recommended in Android.
Refer this [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks).

The CountDownTimer class in Android itself uses a Handler internally.

You could make an handler and pass a runnable to it.
Something like this:

```
        int numberOfTimers = 3;
        int numberOfSeconds = 10;

        Handler timerHandler = new Handler();

    /**
     * Inner class that implements {@link Runnable} to check the timer updates.
     */
    class RunnableTimer implements Runnable {
        int numberOfSeconds;
        int secRemaining;
        int timesRemaining;

        RunnableTimer(int numberOfSeconds, int timesRemaining) {
            this.numberOfSeconds = numberOfSeconds;
            this.timesRemaining = timesRemaining;
            secRemaining = numberOfSeconds;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(secRemaining>0){
                    --secRemaining; // decrease the remaining seconds by 1.
                    updateText() // upadate the textView with remaining seconds.
                    handler.postDelayed(this,1000); // repeat the runnable after 1 sec
                }else {
                    timesRemaining--; // decrease the number of timer by 1 when countdown finishes
                    updateTextWhenTimerFinished() // update the text when the countdown finishes
                    playSound(); // play the sound

                    // check if the timer has to run more times
                    if( timesRemaining > 0 ){
                        secRemaining = numberOfSeconds; // re-initialize the timer seconds
                        handler.postDelayed(this,1000); // repeat the runnable after 1 sec
                    }   
                }
        }

        RunnableTimer timerRunnable = new RunnableTimer(numberOfSeconds, numberOfTimers);

       //finally pass the runnable in the handler to start the timer
       timerHandler.post(timerRunnable);
```

Don't forget to call timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable) in onStop() of your activity.